# image link is broken when embedded into my homepage

Tags: html, https

I have this link :

http://claystudio.rf.gd/images/image003.png

this link is alive. But when i insert into my homepage (different hosting from my image above) :

```
<img src="http://claystudio.rf.gd/images/image003.png">
```

The link is broken, the image won't show up.

Any idea what the problem is ?

Comment: The link gives a `403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 1):

The host server does not support `https` and when linking with `http` it seems to be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

This host is using `http` instead of `https` and when we try to send request to fetch the image then it returns **403** which means the server understood the request, but will not fulfill it.

And there is no way to access this image in your website instead of hosting this image to another host's.